# How to set Gradle's indent

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I use Android Studio. I want to set Gradle's indent, but that config item was not found. For example, I want to set

```
ext.config = [
        'compileSdk': 28,
        'minSdk'    : 21,
        'targetSdk' : 28
]
```

to

```
ext.config = [
    'compileSdk': 28,
    'minSdk': 21,
    'targetSdk': 28
]
```

Do you have any good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Groovy code style should apply to the Gradle build files (unless they are `.kts` in which case Kotlin style applies):

[image: Groovy]